# Returning fields and count in the same sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a specific query i can't figure out how to get done.

I need to return the values of my articles table named Articulos, and count how many times each article is used on every budget.

i have a detail table called pre_detalle which contains a field called idart, where the articulos.id are written in case of being included.

i need each counter to be returned as cont_num.

this is the query i tried to develop:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(articulos.id) as cont_num
FROM articulos
WHERE articulos.id IN(SELECT idart FROM pre_detalle)
GROUP BY articulos.id
ORDER BY cont_num
```

Comment: You can't `GROUP BY` the fields that you are aggregating if you want it to you. You should be listing all other fields that you are `SELECT`ing in the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i needed to do, a couple hours later and after lots of tries i managed to get it working.
SELECT articulos.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pre_detalle WHERE pre_detalle.idart = articulos.id) AS cont_num FROM articulos

Comment: Using subquery in select list should be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you need to count a list of item that you display.
In most cases, you will use a pagination system to display your rows of data.
In most cases, if you try to do it with the same query, it will simply fail.
So, maybe you should get in mind to do it using one query to count the rows and another one to get the rows you want.

In most cases, this answer could help you (in a proper way).

Comment: Any example of how could i do it?

Comment: I recommend to use a framework and an ORM
Some query's clauses change but this where clause is the same other things may be similar. change the fields (* / COUNT(*)) and set a LIMIT to the query of result list.